# Как передаются указатели на переменные при записи/чтении *fstream

Tags: c++, файлы, потоки-данных, c++17

```
Token* ReadToken(std::ifstream* file) {

    lu dist;
    hu length;
    BYTE chr;

    file->read((char*)(&dist), sizeof(dist));
    file->read((char*)(&length), sizeof(length));
    file->read((char*)(&chr), sizeof(chr));

    Token* newToken = new Token;
    newToken->dist = dist;
    newToken->length = length;
    newToken->character = chr;

    return newToken;
}
```

Как избавиться от локальных переменных, используя элементы класса в *read()*?

Comment: А в чем трудность? Что-то в духе `(char*)&newToken->dist, sizeof(newToken->dist)`

Comment: у вас метки С++ ,  значит ориентируйтесь на обьекты:  забудьте слово " переменное", есть только обьекты.  Указатели на обьекты  файлового потока  fstream передаются точно также как и другие: в него записывается адрес  обьекта

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ваш код выдает ошибку

Comment: Я же не экстрасенс. Какую?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Уже поправил скобками

Comment: (char*)&(newToken->dist), sizeof(newToken->dist)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat плюс, раз мы и так с указателем имеем дело - можно опустить &

Comment: Странно, по идее скобки здесь не должны ни на что влиять. Но раз работает, то ладно. :)